# adding display none based on post status in walker menu

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I'm trying to add a display:none to a walker menu in functions but it's not working.

Basically if post status is "draft" then...

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

```
            if ( isset( $item->classes[0] ) && ! empty( $item->classes[0] ) ) {
                $custom_class_data = ' data-classes="' . $item->classes[0] . '"';
            }

            $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . $class_columns . '"' : '';

            $style = $style ? ' style="' . esc_attr( $style ) . '"' : '';

            $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args );
            $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
            global $post;
            $page_id = $post->ID;; // example id of your page 
            $page = get_page( $page_id );
            if( $page->post_status == 'draft' ) : 
            $output .= '<li role="menuitem" style="display: none"' . $id . ' ' . $class_names . ' ' . $column_width . $custom_class_data . $style . ' >';
            else:
            $output .= '<li role="menuitem" ' . $id . ' ' . $class_names . ' ' . $column_width . $custom_class_data . $style . ' >';
            endif;
            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

        } // End if().
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have `$style` variable that stores styles, I would do something like that:

```
// code...
if( $page->post_status == 'draft' )  {
    $style = 'display: none;';
    // if $style was previously initialized
    // $style += 'display: none;';
}
$style = $style ? ' style="' . esc_attr( $style ) . '"' : '';
$output .= '<li role="menuitem"' . $id . ' ' . $class_names . ' ' . $column_width . $custom_class_data . $style . ' >';
// rest of the code
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, maybe you need to see the whole file: Here's the URL to the whole file: https://codeshare.io/anPrzV

Answer (score 1):

You are using `global $post` to check for the status, but that refers to the current page, so it won't work properly.

**Hide the menu item in the nav**

I assume this is in the `start_el` function, and the `$item` variable passed in has the details of the page/post to add to the menu, so you can check the status directly like this:

```
if( $item->post_status == 'draft' )
```

Your updated code would be:

```
if ( isset( $item->classes[0] ) && ! empty( $item->classes[0] ) ) {
    $custom_class_data = ' data-classes="' . $item->classes[0] . '"';
}

$class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . $class_columns . '"' : '';

$style = $style ? ' style="' . esc_attr( $style ) . '"' : '';

$id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args );
$id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

if( $item->post_status == 'draft' ) : 
    $output .= '<li role="menuitem" style="display: none"' . $id . ' ' . $class_names . ' ' . $column_width . $custom_class_data . $style . ' >';
else:
    $output .= '<li role="menuitem" ' . $id . ' ' . $class_names . ' ' . $column_width . $custom_class_data . $style . ' >';
endif;
$output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
```

**Alternative: Don't include the link at all in the nav**

As they are just draft pages you shouldn't include them at all - `display:none` just hides them from the display they are still included in the HTML, so the urls can easily be seen by checking the HTML, and Google will still try to follow the links.

I'd suggest checking the status as the first thing in your function, and if its draft, return wothout doing anything, otherwise process the item as normal.

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    // don't add page/post if it is draft
    if( $item->post_status == 'draft' ) return;

    // if its not draft, process as normal
    [...]

}
```

**Note: Posts with other statuses**

Draft posts are not normally included so I assume you are using custom code to get the posts/pages to display. In that case, don't forget about posts with a status of `future`, `private` or `trash` also.

Comment: That didn't work for me so I've posted the whole file. It doesn't seem to pick up the page id.

Comment: @Jane your code share is for the NavWalker from the Avada theme. Where is your own function that includes the code in your question? We can't help you fix broken code if you don't show it to us!

Comment: It's not broken, I'm trying to adapt it to not show links that are set draft. This file sits in my child theme.

Comment: @Jane I'm confused... you posted code in the question and said that you said isn't working, so I thought that was the code we were trying to fix. So where's that code?